# catching errors and exiting

Tags: python, error-handling, terminate, terminate-handler

In python, is there a way to exit a class after testing a condition, without exiting out of python?

Say I have the class

```
class test():
     def __init__(self):
         self.a = 2

     def create_b(self):
         self.b = 3

     def does_b_exist(self):
         if <self.b doesnt exist>:
             #terminate

         self.b += 1
```

try/except` doesn't work since the rest of the program doesn't terminate after failing. I'm basically trying to catch an error, and do what python does when it shows you errors, but i cant figure out how to do it

Comment: So you want the whole program to end on the "#terminate" line? That'd be a job for sys.exit(), but see my answer if that's not exactly what you want. A better description would help ;)

Comment: You can exit from the `does_b_exist()` method by using `return`.

Comment: The concept of "exit a class" doesn't really make any sense. First off, you aren't "in" the class; you're running a method of an object.

Comment: I think what you want to do is `raise` an exception that will either pass control to a `try/except` handler the caller has set up (that, say, prints an error message), or terminates the program if there's no handler for it.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to run "python -i", which takes you to an interactive console after program execution, to run sys.exit(), which terminates the program, or you (probably) want to customize [sys.excepthook](http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys.excepthook). Describe the behavior you want in a little more detail and we can give you some code to try.

Comment: Which of the options was it? :)

Answer (score 0):

`quit()` is a decent option. It will quit the process, but make sure to clean up before you do. You could consider throwing an uncaught exception and using finally statements as your script aborts cleanly.

Comment: What? A class certainly is callable. Calling it constructs an instance. :)